# Create custom "mode-hook" for other programming languages

Tags: major-mode, compile

For C/C++, I have the following to be run when I do `M-x compile` on a .c/.cpp file

```
(add-hook 'c++-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (set (make-local-variable 'compile-command)
                 (concat "g++ " buffer-file-name " && ./a.out"  ) )))
```

Now, say I work on some other languages that do not have mode-hook, say R. 
I want to do something like this:

```
(add-hook 'r-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (set (make-local-variable 'compile-command)
                 (concat "Rscript " buffer-file-name ) )))
```

After putting above code in my init.el and reloading emacs, there are no errors on startup.  I went ahead and open and .r file, but `M-x compile` does not result in: Rscript .  Instead, I got the default prompt from `M-x compile`: make -k.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Why do you believe that `r-mode` does not have a mode hook?  Do you have a link to the source code for `r-mode` so that we can have a look for ourselves to see whether that is accurate, and/or to make specific suggestions based upon our review of that source code?

Comment: All major modes defined with `define-derived-mode` have a mode hook (`foo-mode-hook` if the mode is named `foo-mode`), and any major modes defined without that macro are expected to do the same thing.  As such, the problem *probably* isn't what you think it is.  I don't have an `r-mode` so, as @lawlist says, please show us the source for that.

Comment: Failing anything else, you could always use `after-change-major-mode-hook` and `(when (derived-mode-p 'r-mode) ...)` in your hook function.

Comment: It would also be worth checking the value of `C-h v major-mode` in one of your `.r` file buffers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know, there's no `r-mode` in Emacs.  Instead, you're probably using ESS's support for R, whose major mode is called `ess-r-mode` IIRC, so you'd want to use `ess-r-mode-hook`.  But as @phils said: check the value of `major-mode` to be sure.

Comment: And most likely «C-h m» will reveal the name of the hook(s) as well